# Xcode storyboard device and simulator needs to be same

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

So i'm about 75% done with my iOS app and have began testing it, apparently the story board device needs to be the same as the simulated device for some UI components which are calculated based on device width.

So when I have set the story board view as iPhone 5s and ran the app in an iPhone X device the components that are taking its width based on the screen width is looking messed up. Why is it taking the story board screen width instead of the actual device width.

Will this happen when I run it in the actual device as well? Also when i'm going to release the app to the app store I would face the same problem.

Comment: It might be bug in xcode and while running app on actual device everything works fine if your components taking width according to device width.

Comment: Have you use auto layout?

Comment: yes I have used auto layout and it works fine with all other ui components. For some reason the gradient is causing the problem as I've set gradient frame to the view bounds. And when I run the story board as 5S and run the simulator as X the gradient takes the 5s height and width. I hope this is an issue with xcode 9 and wont affect the app running on actual device

Answer (score 0):

If you used auto layout then this is happening due to leading space constraint, if you set leading space constraint of any UI element from its super view then width will increase according to device width, and if you want fix width on all device then remove leading width constraint and set width constraint fix.

Comment: Isn't it a bad UI development method to use fixed width and height for components when i'm building a responsive app.