# How do I know if I made auto-layout good enough to fit every device?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In my case:

When I set device to be Iphone SE and run simulator on Ipod touch 7th gen everything is normal and every element is where it should be.

But if I change device to iPhone 11 and run on same simulator (IPod touch 7th gen) almost everything is messed up. Should I always set device to be same as simulator device or it doesn't matter?

[image].     [image]

The title of this question is also my question: Does [Xcode storyboard device and simulator needs to be same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259443/xcode-storyboard-device-and-simulator-needs-to-be-same) ?

Edit:

The upper stack view(username; password) is causing my problem and here is how I made it.
First I've added stack view then inside I put two textFields.

Stack view components:
Axis: Vertical
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill Equally
Spacing: 30

Stack view constraints:

Alignc Center X to: Safe Area

Top Space to: image(image above stack view)
Equals: 17.6

Aspect Ratio to: Superview
Instrinct Size(Default) and also everything else is default

Username label has only one constraint and its aspect ratio = 6:1

Button customization is making the problem and here is what I've used:

```
  class customElements{
   static func styleTextField(_ textfield:UITextField) {
    
    // Create the bottom line
    let bottomLine = CALayer()
    
    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textfield.frame.height - 2, width: textfield.frame.width, height: 2)
    
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 48/255, green: 173/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    
    // Remove border on text field
    textfield.borderStyle = .none
    
    // Add the line to the text field
    textfield.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    
}
```

Comment: In general, I look at the smallest device and largest device for iPhone and iPad, if it works on those, then it should be good

Comment: So it doesn't matter if your chosen device isn't the same size as the simulator device...I was hoping...@MadProgrammer

Comment: You can configure the storyboard to show different devices, but I'd always test in the simulator or, preferably, a real device and check things like orientation changes.  I've had issues where the storyboard layout worked in both portrait and landscape, but wouldn't work on the device 

Comment: I thought that problem you faced is impossible...Anyway I tried every device with storyboard it's perfect but I didn't know that storyboard device can change simulator appearance even if the simulator is always the same device like it's in my case.@MadProgrammer

Comment: One thing I got told early on when I first started with iOS, "always test on the physical device".  I appreciate that this isn't always possible.  At my last job, I used my mum's and wife's "small form factor" devices to proof that the UI design we'd been provided wouldn't work as the company refused to purchase those form factors (but we could only run the app on devices) - I think we were getting the ex-executive's devices 

Comment: I guess that is one of the reasons why most programmers prefer to do everything programmatically. IB is still kinda messed up. @MadProgrammer

Comment: You could verify the layout using snapshot testing on different screen sizes. Point free has an open source library that may be of use to you: https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing

It's definitely less work than running your app on multiple devices each time you change something. And you can use your recorded snapshot to verify that nothing breaks in the future. Kinda a win win.

Comment: I didn't know about that thank you so much. I don't know anything about snapshot testing but I'll learn somewhere. @LloydKeijzer

Comment: *"... if I change device to iPhone 11 and run on same simulator (IPod touch 7th gen) almost everything is messed up ..."* -- There are some very minor differences between layout in IB / Storyboard and layout on simulator and layout on device, but... getting "messed up layout" based on selected device form in IB means you have not setup your constraints correctly.

Comment: I'm not using any leading or trailing constraints just aspect ratio. Because of constant values they make. @DonMag

Comment: @Nikola - you posted tiny pictures, so it's difficult to tell what all is going wrong. You also didn't post any details about your layout constraints. So, if you edit your question and include the details, we can help you fix your layout.

Comment: I've added all details about stack view and its elements hope it's more clear now. @DonMag

Comment: @Nikola - So, what's creating the green lines? I'm guessing you're using some custom text field? What happens if you change them to default `UITextField` (give them a background color so you can see the frames)?

Comment: YESSS that was causing the problem thank you but how?. I just commented lines that customized buttons and added blue background to them and it works perfectly. I uploaded how I customized buttons. @DonMag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - so the problem is not with auto-layout...

The problem is that your **code** is setting the frame of your "bottomLine" layer incorrectly.

Most likely, you're calling your `styleTextField()` func in `viewDidLoad()`. However, UIKit has not set the frames of the views / UI elements yet.

You need to wait until the frames are set - such as in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. A new problem will crop up though, as that can be (and usually is) called multiple times, and your code would be creating and adding multiple "bottomLine" layers.

A better option would be to subclass `UITextField` and handle the layer frame in `layoutSubviews()`.

Here's a quick sample:

```
@IBDesignable
class StyleTextField: UITextField {
    
    @IBInspectable
    var lineColor: UIColor = UIColor.init(red: 48/255, green: 173/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1) {
        didSet {
            bottomLine.backgroundColor = lineColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    private let bottomLine: CALayer = CALayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        // needs to be set here for Storyboard / IB
        self.borderStyle = .none
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        // remove border
        self.borderStyle = .none
        
        // bottom line color
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = lineColor.cgColor

        // add bottom line layer
        layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // update bottom line layer frame
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height - 2.0, width: bounds.width, height: 2)
    }
    
}
```

Now, in Storyboard / IB, when you assign `StyleTextField` as the custom class of your `UITextField` the "bottomLine" will be added and framed automatically - no need to be calling any other func.

And, by coding this as `@IBDesignable`, we see how it looks in Storyboard:

[image]

Also, I added `lineColor` as an `@IBInspectable` property, as an example of something you can change in Storyboard:

[image]

[image]